# Changing x axis ticks in ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2

I am using the following code to plot my data frame `d` (provided below):

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=ID, y=Value)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

I want now to change the axis ticks of the x axis. For that I use:

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=d$ID, y=d$Value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:8,
                   labels=c("05/11", "29/11", "11/12", "23/12",
                            "04/01", "16/01", "28/01", "09/02"))
```

However, the result is not as expected. There are no x axis ticks at all.
[image]

My data frame `d`:

```
> str(d)
'data.frame':    10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Value    : num  0.021 0.0436 0.0768 0.0901 0.1128 ...
 $ Statistic: Factor w/ 1 level "Variable": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ ID       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Variable : chr  "Mean_Sigma0_VV" "Mean_Sigma0_VV" "Mean_Sigma0_VV" "Mean_Sigma0_VV" ...

> dput(d)
structure(list(Value = c(0.021008858735161, 0.0435905957091736, 
0.0767780373205124, 0.0901182900951117, 0.11277978896612, 0.0990637045976107, 
0.118897251291308, 0.10604101636234, 0.121525916187773, 0.104460360304768
), Statistic = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), class = "factor", .Label = "Variable"), ID = 1:10, Variable = c("Mean_Sigma0_VV", 
"Mean_Sigma0_VV", "Mean_Sigma0_VV", "Mean_Sigma0_VV", "Mean_Sigma0_VV", 
"Mean_Sigma0_VV", "Mean_Sigma0_VV", "Mean_Sigma0_VV", "Mean_Sigma0_VV", 
"Mean_Sigma0_VV")), .Names = c("Value", "Statistic", "ID", "Variable"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: _"I want now to change the values of the x axes"_ is a very vague statement. You probably want to use `scale_x_continuous`, not `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: I did fix the issue thank you. I was using `scale_x_discrete` in another code with similar data and it was working.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that every time you use a `$` operator inside your `aes()` statement your code is likely broken. Even if it seems to work it's wrong.

Comment: @ClausWilke, thank your for pointing it out. You mean then that it's better to use `aes(x=ID, y=Value)` than `aes(x=d$ID, y=d$Value)`. What do you mean by "the code is broken"? Is it just a matter of good practice?

Comment: "The code is wrong" means the behavior is undefined and just because it works now doesn't mean it'll always work. I suggest you read up on aesthetic mappings. Also, if there's nothing on this topic on SO (do a careful search) you could ask a separate question specifically about that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ID` is a numeric column, so ggplot2 uses a continuous scale, not a discrete scale:

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=ID, y=Value)) + 
  geom_line()  + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:8,
                     labels=c("05/11", "29/11", "11/12", "23/12",
                              "04/01", "16/01", "28/01", "09/02"))
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to use a discrete scale, you need to convert `ID` into a factor. However, in this case ggplot2 would not normally group separate `ID` values together and connect them with a single line. To achieve that, you have to add `group = 1` (to put everything into the same group).

```
d$ID <- factor(d$ID)

ggplot(data=d, aes(x = ID, y = Value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:8,
                   labels=c("05/11", "29/11", "11/12", "23/12",
                            "04/01", "16/01", "28/01", "09/02"))
```

[image]

You can see that the two figures are almost but not exactly the same. Axis-range expansion beyond the data limit works slightly differently for discrete and continuous scales. Also, continuous scales have minor grid lines and discrete scales do not.